# How to post the values of textboxes of a given class to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have some dynamically generated textboxes which are generated using PHP and have a CSS Class 'hide' with CSS styling 'display:none' to determine if the textboxes will be visible.

On the click of a button, some of JQuery (.removeClass) is used to make some of the textboxes visible.

The challenging part, I want to post the values of the textboxes which do not have the class 'hide' to my SQL database.

I believe to do this I need to use JavaScript(JQuery), but I do not have the algorithm figured out.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code used to generate the textboxes.

```
<div class="form-group has-success res">
      <?php
            $sql = "SELECT moduleid, modulename FROM modules";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<div class='hide alert alert-success  alert-dismissible fade in ".$row['moduleid']."' role='alert'>";
                echo "<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>";
                echo "<input type'text' name='module' class='hide' value='".$row['moduleid']."' placeholder='".$row['moduleid']."' />";
                echo "<div class='i'> <strong>".$row['moduleid']."</strong></div>".$row['modulename']."</div>";

            }
      ?>
</div>
```

Comment: How strong is your javascript. You will require some ajax calls to make this happen. this should get you started http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `"textbox"(input)` into `form`, and add `disabled="disabled"` to your hidden `input` to prevent value of hidden input from posting to server.

```
<form action="/url_path_for_handling_the_post.php">
    <input type'text' name='module1' class='hide' disabled="disabled" value='bar' />
    <input type'text' name='module2' value='foo' />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

For the above example, only value of input named module2 will be sent to server.

In the server side to get all Input values:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    //do something
    echo $key . ' has the value of ' . $value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment, This works okay and i am able to do this, so i can also use javascript to set the property of the input that are not required to disabled but then there is an issue with implementation when it comes to PHP because the amount of enabled inputs would be a variable. Do you know how to implement adding this enabled input to the database?